# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Laravel and change

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, eager-loading

I have double foreach here:

> ID
>             ISBN
>             Klasifikasi
>             Lokasi
>             Cp_Or
>             Tahun
>             ID_Master_Buku   
>             Jenis
>             Status
>             Tgl_Masuk
>             can_issue
>             ID
>             Edisi
>             Pengarang
>             Deskripsi
>             Penerbit
>             Judul
>             Jumlah_Buku
>             Bahasa
>             Gambar
>             Subjek
>             Topik
>
> ```
> @foreach($bukus as $buku)
> dd($buku)
> @foreach($buku->tmbuku as $item)
> <tr>
>         <td>{{$buku->ID}}</td>        
>         <td>{{$buku->ISBN}}</td>
>         <td>{{$buku->Klasifikasi}}</td>
>         <td>{{$buku->Lokasi}}</td>
>         <td>{{$buku->Cp_Or}}</td>
>         <td>{{$buku->Tahun}}</td>
>         <td>{{$buku->ID_Master_Buku}}</td>
>         <td>{{$buku->Jenis}}</td>
>         <td>{{$buku->Status}}</td>
>         <td>{{$buku->Tgl_Masuk}}</td>
>         <td>{{$buku->can_issue}}</td>
>         <td>{{$item->ID}}</td>
>         <td>{{$item->Edisi}}</td>
>         <td>{{$item->Pengarang}}</td>     
>         <td>{{$item->Deskripsi}}</td>
>         <td>{{$item->Penerbit}}</td>
>         <td>{{$item->Judul}}</td>
>         <td>{{$item->Jumlah_Buku}}</td>
>         <td>{{$item->Bahasa}}</td>
>         <td>{{$item->Gambar}}</td>        
>         <td>{{$item->Subjek}}</td>
>         <td>{{$item->Topik}}</td>
>         @endforeach
> </tr>
> @endforeach
>  </table>
> ```

here is my controller:

> get();
>         return View::make('EagerLoading.index',compact('bukus'));
>     } }

I have model here

> hasMany('TDbuku','ID','ID_Master_Buku');
>         
>     }
> }

then i got error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Laravel

when i change a line code like this:

> return $this->hasMany('TDbuku','ID_Master_Buku','ID');

i got this error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
> 't_m_buku.ID_Master_Buku' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from
> `t_m_buku` where `t_m_buku`.`ID_Master_Buku` in (01.00001, 01.00002)

Could you please tell me whats wrong there?
I want to select all data from 2 table using eagerLoading

Comment: Pretty simple, just look at your error. It looks like your Column `t_m_buku.ID_Master_Buku` does not exist.

Comment: ya, thats the matter. i dont need to make it. How it could be and how do i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Model TMbuku:

   ```
    class TMbuku extends \Eloquent{

     public function tdbukus(){
        return $this->hasMany('TDbuku','ID','ID_Master_Buku');
     }
   }
   ```
2. Model TDbuku:

   ```
    class TDbuku extends \Eloquent{

        public function tmbukus(){

        return $this->belongsToMany('TMbuku');
      }

    }
   ```

In Any controller you can get like this:

```
$tmbukus = TMbuku::with('tdbukus')->get();
$tmbukus = $tmbukus->toArray();
echo '<pre>'; print_r($tmbukus); exit;
```

Comment: i got this

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 01.00001
            [ISBN] => 9795523406
            [Klasifikasi] => 005.133 Tos c Kp.1
            [Lokasi] => Lt.1, R18/3
            [Cp_Or] => Original
            [Tahun] => 2000
            [ID_Master_Buku] => 574
            [Jenis] => 16
            [Status] => 4
            [Tgl_Masuk] => 2011-07-26
            [can_issue] => nono
            [tmbuku] => 
        )

does it mean there is no data in another table? how do i fix it?

Comment: put this in your controller and get sql query copy/paste into phpmyadmin : - $tmbukus = $tmbukus->toArray(); $queries = DB::getQueryLog();$last_query = end($queries); print_r($last_query);exit;